# external currency converter api returning no data in angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

In service I am trying to get the conversion. The api call result is nothing. in **Browser Network** , it shows status code **200**, but `method` **OPTIONS**, not **GET** . CORS is allowed for any origin, method and header. 
And there should be a **GET** call after this **OPTION** call. but Option call may be saying to not call get. How do I figure out whats happening?

I am using Angular 5. Here is my code :

```js
getCurrencyWisePriceFromBDT(price: number, toCurrency: string): any {
  let currencyConversionUrl = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=BDT_";
  currencyConversionUrl = currencyConversionUrl + toCurrency;

  console.log(currencyConversionUrl);
  let rateInNewCurrency;
  this.http.get < any > (currencyConversionUrl).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    rateInNewCurrency = data.val;
    console.log(rateInNewCurrency);
    return rateInNewCurrency * price;
  });
}
```

In Chrome its showing this error :

```js
Failed to load https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=BDT_USD: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cybsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. (I only switched to https to make sure chrome doesn't block the request becuase of mixed content (request from https siackblitz url to http url); are you looking at what is printed in the browser console, or do you expect your method to actually return something?

Comment: i am looking both console and network . there is only one Options request in this domain. NO GET. I have checked the stackblitz. may be some other thing of my application is blocking!!! ???

Comment: @JBNizet question updated, please check

Comment: Well, the message says it all. You're sending a request with an Authorization header, but that header is not allowed.

Comment: how do I remove authorization header from the request?

Comment: You shouldn't remove it. Instead, you should avoid setting it in the first place. You probably have an interceptor adding that header to all requests. It should only add it to requests that need it (i.e. most probably to the requests that go to your own backend, but not to requests that go to external URLs)

Comment: are you using any CORS plugin in chrome ?

Comment: @JBNizet I understand the process. but in few other external urls are using auth access token as well, like aws in my app. just this api is out of every thing. so should I handle it this way?

Comment: @KesavanR No, I am not using any CORS plugin in chrome.

Comment: Well, yes. Either use a whitelist and add the header only if the URL is in the whitelist, or use a blacklist, and add the header except if the URL is in the blacklist. In any case, you must not send this header to that external currendy converter api. I would definitely use a whitelist: sending your secret authorization token to a third-party, who could use it to impersonate you, is not really a good idea.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added a check of url to exclude the auth header in app.interceptor and worked for me well. Thanks. you can create an answer which may help to other.

Answer (score 1):

```
getCurrencyWisePriceFromBDT(price: number, toCurrency: string): any {
  const currencyFormat = `BDT_${toCurrency}`;
  const currencyConversionUrl =`https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=${currencyFormat}`;
  console.log(currencyConversionUrl);
  let rateInNewCurrency;
  this.http.get < any > (currencyConversionUrl).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    rateInNewCurrency = data.results[currencyFormat].val;
    console.log(rateInNewCurrency);
    return rateInNewCurrency * price;
  });
```

`rateInNewCurrency` returns `0.01193` if you pass `50` and `'USD'` to `getCurrencyWisePriceFromBDT(50,'USD')` Is this what you were looking for?
If yes then, when you subscribe your response data object is in following format.
`data.results.BDR_USD.val` based on Currency passed to URL.

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9bdzm)

Comment: My `GET` call is not taking place. Its showing only the preflight method `options` and not get method.

Comment: In chrome developers console, at network tab check xhr requests and in that select free.currencyconverterapi.com or convert?BDT_USD and see headers to check which all headers are set, when you make get request.

Comment: your currencyFormat declaration helped me. Though the problem was handled by adding the url in app interceptor to not add authorize if this url found.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)